# .app domain and cloudfront/s3 via Namecheap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I just want to say first - I did exact same steps / settings for an .io domain and it works perfectly.
Trying to repeat the steps for .app domain [which is 'special' thanks to google] causes my redirect to not work properly.
I have an s3 bucket that cloudfront is pointing to. [www.domain.io](http://www.domain.io) works fine domain.io works fine.
Second bucket, second cloudfront distribution - [www.domain.app](http://www.domain.app) works fine, domain.app times out.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The .app top-level domain is included on the HSTS preload list - are you using HTTPS or HTTP? If HTTP, you will have to set up SSL to enforce HTTPS

Comment: I'm using https, since I have the AWS SSL certificate - should I switch this in namecheap as well somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

An s3 endpoint is `HTTP` and `.app` domains require `HTTPS`. I used CloudFront to solve for this.

Have CloudFront point to your s3 bucket. Apply an SSL cert from ACM to secure the CloudFront endpoint. Then in NameCheap point to the secure CloudFront endpoint.